# Hibernate could not load requested class with composite id

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

I used Hibernate Code Generation tool in eclipse plugins to generate pojo classes, hbm files and DAO classes for the [world database](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-other.html). This generated City.java, Country.java, Countrylanguage.java and CountrylanguageId.java, but only three hbm files City.hbm.xml Country.hbm.xml and Countrylanguage.hbm.xml.

I have added the java class files in the configuration through addClass

```
    protected SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    Configuration config = new Configuration()
            .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
            .addClass(Country.class)
            .addClass(City.class)
            .addClass(Countrylanguage.class);
```

But on attempting to create the service registry using

```
StandardServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(config.getProperties()).build();
```

It throws the following error -

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.component.PojoComponentTuplizer]
at org.hibernate.tuple.component.ComponentTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(ComponentTuplizerFactory.java:107)
at org.hibernate.tuple.component.ComponentTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(ComponentTuplizerFactory.java:128)
at org.hibernate.tuple.component.ComponentMetamodel.<init>(ComponentMetamodel.java:77)
at org.hibernate.tuple.component.ComponentMetamodel.<init>(ComponentMetamodel.java:52)
at org.hibernate.mapping.Component.getType(Component.java:227)
at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:455)
at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:268)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:343)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:461)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
at dao.DefaultService.getSessionFactory(DefaultService.java:24)
at dao.DefaultService.<init>(DefaultService.java:14)
at dao.CityService.<init>(CityService.java:21)
at App.main(App.java:6)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.hibernate.tuple.component.ComponentTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(ComponentTuplizerFactory.java:104)
... 13 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: component class not found: CountrylanguageId
at org.hibernate.mapping.Component.getComponentClass(Component.java:177)
at org.hibernate.tuple.component.PojoComponentTuplizer.setComponentClass(PojoComponentTuplizer.java:147)
at org.hibernate.tuple.component.AbstractComponentTuplizer.<init>(AbstractComponentTuplizer.java:37)
at org.hibernate.tuple.component.PojoComponentTuplizer.<init>(PojoComponentTuplizer.java:41)
... 18 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [CountrylanguageId]
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:133)
at org.hibernate.mapping.Component.getComponentClass(Component.java:174)
... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : CountrylanguageId
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(AggregatedClassLoader.java:210)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:130)
... 22 more
```

I tried adding

> .addClass(CountrylanguageId.class)

but this throws up another error that the corresponding hbm file Countrylanguage.hbm.xml is missing.

Are hbm files needed for Classes which are generated based on composite-id relations ? Why does this error surface even though the class has been specified in the hibernate configuration instance ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue.
Using the hibernate tool when I generated the pojo classes, I specified it to be default package, but generated them under a sub-folder src/main/java/entity.

The hbm files have been updated to have the *class="..."* references and *name="..."* references to be entity.Countrylanguage, after which it is working fine.

Also verified that using hibernate generation tool configured with package as entity, and folder as default src/main/java outputs the hbm files correctly as expected.

Will mark this question as answered and close it.